# Incorporate a gameObject upon a rotating gameObject so that it follow the rotation motion

Tags: c#, rotation, unity-game-engine, gameobject, collider

(This is a 2d project) I want to incorporate, temporarily (having the chance to separate them), if collide is detected, an "a" gameObject with another rotating gameObject so that the former follow the rotating movement of the latter.

```
void Start () {
        cent = new Vector3 (0,0,1);
    }

void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col)
    {
    if(col.tag == "obstacle")
        {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        rb.Sleep ();
        transform.Translate (playerRoom.transform.position);
        transform.RotateAround (center.transform.position, cent, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }   
    }
```

I tried, creating an empty gameObject as a child of the rotating object and setting this point as a "room" to host the first object to get the job easier, but I am not able to translate "a" gameObject every frame it runs.

Comment: Please provide a MCVE - the code that you currently have and what you've tried.

Comment: @MLavrentyev take a look now please

Comment: @MLavrentyev can you give me some help please?